# Pepper movement not working with choregraphe behaviour

Tags: robotics, pepper

I'm trying to let Pepper do a really basic sequence of movements, with Choregraphe: a rotation, then one meter forward, than another rotation and finally one meter forward.
Most of the times that I'm running the behaviour, the sequence cannot be completed as the robot freezes. Every time I can hear the noise of the motors, but most of the times the robot won't move. Please consider that it is on a perfectly smooth surface.
Does anybody know what could be the reason of this problem? Do you have any suggestion on how to fix it?

The version of NAOqi is 2.5.5.5

[image: box flow in choregraph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mcaniot says the robot has some aggressive safety features and the robot may stop suddenly. However if you know what you are doing and accept the risk, you can disable the security in the web settings.

Read the specifics of the collision avoidance here:
http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/reflexes-external-collision.html#pepp-pepper

You can find the settings to disable it here:
[image: Allow for security features to be disabled]

Use this method to enable/disable settings:
http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/reflexes-external-collision-api.html#ALMotionProxy::setExternalCollisionProtectionEnabled__ssCR.bCR

Answer (score 1):

The robot has a lot of safety. If the robot can't move because of an obstacle, the choregraphe box will say that your movement failed (grey output on the move To box) and cancel your flow. In your program, the flow will only continue if the movement is a success.

Comment: As Maxime says, it can be obstacles in the way, you could add a saybox to every grey output saying "i'm blocked", and also try removing all the obstacles on the way (even you). Sometimes sunlight is also seen as an obstacle...